# Why is my break label erroring?

Tags: label, break

Hey guys I am trying to break out of a for loop that searches thru all files and breaks once it finds the file. The best thing I have found is the labeling break but its giving an error saying it doesn't exist can you guys take a look and see what I am doing wrong?

```
    import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.Node;
import org.dom4j.io.SAXReader;
import org.jaxen.dom4j.*;


public class Load 
{
    static String info = "";
    public static String LoadSum(String projNum)
    {
        info = "";
        try
        {
            searching:
            Files.walk(Paths.get("D:/workspace/Project Program/Projects/")).forEach(filePath ->
            {
                if(Files.isRegularFile(filePath))
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Checking");
                        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
                        Document document = reader.read(filePath.toFile());
                        Node node = document.selectSingleNode("//Project/Info/ProjectNumber");
                        String projectNumber = node.getStringValue();
                        if(projNum.equals(projectNumber))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Found it");
                            node = document.selectSingleNode("//Project/Info/Name");
                            info += node.getStringValue() + " : ";
                            //node = document.selectSingleNode("//Project/Info/Owner");
                            info += "Owner" + " : ";
                            node = document.selectSingleNode("//Project/Info/Status");
                            info += node.getStringValue() + " : ";
                            break searching; // error here searching doe not exist
                        }
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return info;
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The break statement is not into a loop, so you cannot use it.

To `forEach` statement accepts an Anonymous function that is applied to all the elements found by the `Paths.get("D:/workspace/Project Program/Projects/"))` statement.

You can stop the operation by throwing an exception, if it's suitable for you.

Source: [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-)

**Edit**: considering the fact that what you are passing is an anonymous function you can wrap all the function block with an if statement that depends on a boolean variable defined outside the function: if you find the element you toggle the variable so for the next elements it will be just a no-op. If you wanna know more about Java lambda expressions look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Comment: Yea that was my plan be was having it just skip checking by having a bool variable to check if it found it but then i found this way so wanted to try it. Thanks for the info.